# std::map - how to lookup or add, then may be delete item in one search

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have such map:

```
std::map<myDecimal, OrderBookItem> buyContainer;
```

I need to lookup (or add), modify, and may be delete the item, something like that:

```
OrderBookItem item = buyContainer[price_];
item.lots += lots_;
if (item.lots == 0) {
    buyContainer.erase(price_);
}
```

But i think I'm "searching" twice. First time `OrderBookItem item = buyContainer[price_];` and second time `buyContainer.erase(price_);` How to rewrite my code so I search just once? Probably using iterator?

**upd**

So far it seems it is not possible to do everything in one search. `operator[]` allows me to lookup or add, but i have to do extra search for deleting. `iterator` allows me to lookup then erase but I have to do extra search to add item if not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find), this will return an iterator which keeps the exact place in the map, if you pass that to erase it won't do a second search. Something like this:

```
std::map<myDecimal, OrderBookItem>::iterator it = buyContainer.find(price_);
OrderBookItem item = it->second;
item.lots += lots_;
if (item.lots == 0) {
    buyContainer.erase(it);
}
```

Also you'd likely want to make a reference out of `item` (`OrderBookItem& item`) so that the actual value in the map gets adjusted, not the local copy.

edit: if you also want to insert (as stated in another comment and update), you can use `lower_bound` instead of `find` as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97050/stdmap-insert-or-stdmap-find). This would be something like this (not tested):

```
std::map<myDecimal, OrderBookItem>::iterator it = buyContainer.lower_bound(price_);

if(it != mymap.end() && !(buyContainer.key_comp()(price_, it->first)))
    OrderBookItem item = it->second;
    item.lots += lots_;
    if (item.lots == 0) {
        buyContainer.erase(it);
    }
} else {
    // determine value (variable v below), e.g. OrderBookItem v{};
    buyContainer.insert(it, std::map<myDecimal, OrderBookItem>::value_type(price_, v));
}
```

The advantage here is you don't run the code related to constructing `v` if the item already exists. You can also use following C++11 solution if that's not really complex code. The advantage is that this also works with `unordered_map` and it still avoids an unnecessary `value_type` construction when it's not necessary.

```
auto insertion = buyContainer.insert({price_, {arguments_to_OrderBookItem_constructor}});

if(insertion.second) // Item already existed, remove if you also want op on new item(s)
{
    auto item = insertion.first->second; //Possibly make auto& as stated above
    item.lots += lots_;
    if (item.lots == 0) {
        buyContainer.erase(insertion.first);
    }
}
```

Without C++11 you can also simply construct a `std::map<myDecimal, OrderBookItem>::value_type` object and supply that to insert instead of the C++11 perfect forwarding. See @Erbureth's answer for that one. But again, you can avoid that construction altogether with the original solution and if you're caring about insert/delete/find performance of map, which is already fast, you might want to exactly do that.

Comment: Shouldn't that be it->second?  Also what happens if nothing is found?

Comment: @Goz correct, thanks for noticing. The insert wasn't handled in original code either, but I added a more elaborate example on the `lower_bound` version that includes inserting without additional lookup.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is

```
std::map<myDecimal, OrderBookItem>::iterator it = buyContainer.find(price_);
if(it != buyContainer.end())
{
   OrderBookItem& item = it->second;
   item.lots += lots_;
   if (item.lots == 0) {
     buyContainer.erase(it);
   }
}
else{ // insert if not existing
     OrderBookItem item;
     item.lots += lots_;
     if (item.lots != 0) {
        buyContainer[price_] = item;
     }
}
```

note that there is a possible bug in the code you posted, because you modify a local object `item` .

Comment: how to modify your code if I also need to insert item if it doesn't exist and still want to do everything in one run? I.e start searching, if doesn't exist then add, update, if lots == 0 then delete.

Comment: @UmNyobe no, you can actually do everything with a single lookup, see both mine and Erbureth's answers.

Comment: Erbureth is just unrolling what the operator [] does to get the iterator. I started on this idea but thought I will make minimal change to original code.

Comment: @UmNyobe If the construction of the `Value` is cheap, I see no problem with it. For more expensive construction, KilianDS' approach is better.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `iterator`:

```
std::map<myDecimal, OrderBookItem> buyContainer;
std::map<myDecimal, OrderBookItem>::iterator item
    = buyContainer.insert(std::makePair(price_, OrderBookItem())).first;

if (satisfiesCond(item->second)) {
    buyContainer.erase(item);
}
```

`iterator` type serves as a pointer to element in an STL container, so the search is performed only once.

[`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) documentation:

> Inserts element(s) into the container, if the container doesn't already contain an element with an equivalent key.

EDIT: This will also create item if it doesn't exist.

Comment: i also need to add item if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use an iterator:

```
std::map<myDecimal, OrderBookItem>::iterator iter = buyContainer.find(price_);
if (iter->second.lots + lots_ == 0) {
    buyContainer.erase(iter);
}
```

Also note that you are not modifying the item in your example since you are not getting a reference but a value (so you copy it). With an iterator you would get a reference. So if you want to modify the item within the map do this:

```
std::map<myDecimal, OrderBookItem>::iterator iter = buyContainer.find(price_);
iter->second.lots += lots_
if (iter->second.lots == 0) {
    buyContainer.erase(iter);
}
```

Comment: how to tell iterator to add value if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

You should erase with the iterator.
First find the iterator which point to your data, then erase your data with the iterator.

Example from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/ :

```
// map::find
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main ()
{
  std::map<char,int> mymap;
  std::map<char,int>::iterator it;

  mymap['a']=50;
  mymap['b']=100;
  mymap['c']=150;
  mymap['d']=200;

  it=mymap.find('b');
  mymap.erase (it);
  mymap.erase (mymap.find('d'));

  // print content:
  std::cout << "elements in mymap:" << '\n';
  std::cout << "a => " << mymap.find('a')->second << '\n';
  std::cout << "c => " << mymap.find('c')->second << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use find() to search your map, this returns an iterator to the position, you can then use erase() with the iterator like so:

```
std::map<myDecimal, OrderBookItem> buyContainer;
std::map<myDecimal, OrderBookItem>::iterator it;

it = buyContainer.find(price_); //only searching map once
if(it != buyContainer.end())
{
    if(it->second += lots_ == 0)
    {
        buyContainer.erase(it);

}
```

Comment: i also need to insert item if it not exist